# MigrationSchemaMissing(Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s) % exc)

Tags: django, postgresql, migration

Steps I did:
1. Deleted migration files.
2.created only one initial migration file.
3. Enter psql command prompt. Connect to database. drop schema public cascade; create schema public;
4.tried to migrate again.

I get MigrationSchemaMissing(Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s) % exc) Error.

Answer (score 9):

This [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106067) and the comment on its question works for me, in brief you must get required grant for a schema as below:

```
grant usage on schema public to username;
grant create on schema public to username;
```

Comment: After I ran this for username=djangouser I'm getting `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_migrations`

Comment: I use host mysql at [.freemysqlhosting.net](https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/) and run `grant usage on schema public to username; grant create on schema public to username;` in [phpmyadmin.co](http://www.phpmyadmin.co), but two commands not execute. Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

I simply deleted the database and recreated and then ran the migration again to solve this problem.

DROP DATABASE *database_name*

%  python manage.py migrate