# CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" bigint NOT NULL PRIMA

Tags: psql, django-migrations

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbapp/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbapp/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 107, in migrate
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/p.gauthamprasad/Downloads/pb/pbvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 72, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" bigint NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^
)
```

I have tried this "command python3 manage.py migrate" after creating database
and linking in settings.py
in this way...:-

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<name>',
        'USER': '<username>',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
```

i have tried grant "commands" in psql there is no use

Answer (score 18):

Applying the following command solves it for me without giving the new user all privileges, just setting him as the owner of the project db.

```
ALTER DATABASE <db_name> OWNER TO <db_user>;
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I faced the exact issue several times and solved by providing permission every single time. Anyone who stumbled in same scenario can try below command in psql CLI:

```
GRANT postgres TO <user>;
```

Answer (score 4):

This database access error.
This is a step by step guide.

1. Create a new role

   `CREATE USER <user name> WITH PASSWORD <'password'> CREATEDB;`
2. Create a database and specify its owner

   `CREATE DATABASE <database name> WITH OWNER <user name>;`

If the database was created earlier and you need to change the owner, use the command

```
`ALTER DATABASE <database name> OWNER TO <user name>;`
```

3. Give the user all rights to the database

   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <db name> TO <user name>;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows this might help you.

Open PG-ADMIN login to local server.
[image]

Right click on your user.
click on properties & select the privileges tab.
Select the superuser option for your user as follows.
[image]

And run your migrations and migrate command again it should work.

If your are on linux you have to check for the permissions.
You can follow below link

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 1):

I got this error many times when dealing with postgres in Django.

Here is how you can solve it.
Go to your terminal and switch to postgres user

```
sudo su posgres & psql
```

***Make sure you select your database first before running the commands***

```
postgres=# \c my_db;

You are now connected to database "my_db" as user "postgres".
```

Then grant the privilege to your user

```
my_db=# GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO my_user;
GRANT
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, after deleting the data, by running the command
`DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;`
and I resolved it by creating the missing schema
`CREATE SCHEMA public;`

Answer (score 0):

The missing link for me was that you need to give access to the public schema. I do not see this documented anywhere but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589076/django-unit-tests-unable-to-create-the-django-migrations-table).

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO <db_user>;
```