# Django "MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (no schema has been selected to create in)"

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to restore a production database to my local machine, similar to the workflow described for Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export). However, I'm using Aptible, which provides a [DB tunnel](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/cli/db-tunnel.html) for this purpose.

Using pgAdmin4, I've created a 'Custom' backup. Then, slightly modifying a pgAdmin command, I've restored it using

```
"/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_restore" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "lucy_prod" --verbose "/Users/kurtpeek/lucy-prod-backup-11-june-2018" --clean
```

where I've added the `--clean` option to drop database objects before recreating them (cf. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html).

The problem is that when I now try to `python manage.py migrate`, I get the following error:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 303, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^
)
```

From what I understand from [MigrationSchemaMissing(Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s) % exc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691932/migrationschemamissingunable-to-create-the-django-migrations-table-s-exc), I need to run

```
grant usage on schema public to username;
grant create on schema public to username;
```

However, what should I fill out for `username`? Should this be `postgres`?

Here are some more details on the `public` schema and the `search_path`:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py dbshell
psql (10.4)
Type "help" for help.

lucy_prod=> \dn+ public
                        List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   | Access privileges |      Description       
--------+----------+-------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres |                   | standard public schema
(1 row)

lucy_prod=> SHOW search_path;
   search_path   
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
```

**Update**

From running the `select current_user;` command, I determined that my current user is named `lucyapp`, but if I try to `grant usage on schema public` for this user I get a 'permission denied' error:

```
lucy_prod=> select current_user;
 current_user 
--------------
 lucyapp
(1 row)

lucy_prod=> grant usage on schema public to lucyapp;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
lucy_prod=> grant create on schema public to lucyapp;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
```

Answer (score 13):

Just changing the database ownership worked for me.

```
ALTER DATABASE database OWNER TO user;
```

Answer (score 10):

This is happening due to the access issue of the role to the `public` schema. Running this script inside the database shell will solve the issue.

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO your_user;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;
```

This is for Postgres DB. A similar script can be found for other SQL DB.

Comment: still got same issue

Comment: should the second one not be" TO you_user" rather than "TO public"?

Comment: usually an explanation of the solution/code is helpful; you defined the problem, and then gave a solution (purportedly), but didn't explain or justify it.  Especially granting privileges on public to public.

Answer (score 3):

Check the user created earlier after db creation and the one set in **DATABASES** configurations in `settings.py` is matching. Lets call it as *myuser* and the db created as *mydb*

Apply below permissions to the user -

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser; 
ALTER DATABASE mydb OWNER TO myuser;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA PUBLIC TO myuser;
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to `GRANT USAGE` and `GRANT CREATE` when I simply entered psql using the `psql` command instead of `python manage.py dbshell`. I subsequently ran into errors relating to the owner of the objects in the database (relations, etc.) not being the one in the `DATABASES['USER']` settings, namely, `'lucyapp'`.

I finally resolved the issues using [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgrestore.html) with the `--no-owner` and `--role=lucyapp` options, following [Postgresql - backup database and restore on different owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469008/postgresql-backup-database-and-restore-on-different-owner).