# Django connection cursor not showing any tables?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to debug an issue in a separate question, [Django "MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (no schema has been selected to create in)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805996/django-migrationschemamissing-unable-to-create-the-django-migrations-table-no): when I try to `python manage.py migrate`, I get an error `no schema has been selected to create in`.

In my version of Django (1.11.9), the `ensure_schema` method of the `MigrationRecorder` is

```
def ensure_schema(self):
    """
    Ensures the table exists and has the correct schema.
    """
    # If the table's there, that's fine - we've never changed its schema
    # in the codebase.
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
        return
    # Make the table
    try:
        with self.connection.schema_editor() as editor:
            editor.create_model(self.Migration)
    except DatabaseError as exc:
        raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
```

(It would appear that in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/recorder.py this is slightly refactored, but essentially the same). Note that I've set a trace at the beginning of the method using `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`.

Now, when I drop into the debugger, I see that `introspection.table_names()` on the `self.connection.cursor()` returns an empty list:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py migrate
> /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py(53)ensure_schema()
     52         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 53         if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
     54             return

ipdb> self.Migration._meta.db_table
'django_migrations'
ipdb> self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
[]
```

So it seems like the database does not contain any tables, and in particular, doesn't contain the `django_migrations` table.

How can this be? If I look at our `DATABASES` setting, it seems to be configured correctly:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: settings.DATABASES
Out[2]: 
{'default': {'NAME': 'lucy_prod',
  'USER': 'lucyapp',
  'PASSWORD': '<our_password>',
  'HOST': 'localhost',
  'PORT': '',
  'CONN_MAX_AGE': 500,
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
  'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
  'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
  'OPTIONS': {},
  'TIME_ZONE': None,
  'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}
```

and in pgAdmin I can see that the database has tables:

[image]

Why are these tables not getting 'picked up' by the `self.connection.cursor()`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to set the owner of the schema to the `DATABASES['USER']`, which in our case is called `'lucyapp'`. In the end, I did this using [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgdump.html) with `--no-owner` and `--role=lucyapp`.